# Header spacers before and after div tag

Tags: html, css

The logo bar div ID leaves a small space between itself and surrounding divs when viewed in responsive mode. Any way to fix this without any major changes being made?

I find this really strange because when viewed outside of responsive mode it seems fine.

Here is the HTML for my homepage:

```css
#navmenu {
      height: 80px;
      z-index: 1;
      background: linear-gradient(white, #a9a9a9);
    }
    
    #logobar {
    
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: white;
     }
    
    #headerlogo {
    
    max-width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 2%;
    }
    
    #iPhone {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    .jQuery {
    
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    max-width: auto;
    }
    
    .spacer {
      width:100%;
      height:300px;
      opacity: 0.3;
      background-color: grey;
      z-index: 1;
      display:block;
    
    }
    
    .smicon {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
    }
    
    .parallax {
      background-image: url(../img/rome2.jpg);
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 0;
    }
    
    .topbar{
    
    height: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    color: black;
    
    }
    
    
    
    .col1-1 {
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
      background-color: #eaebed;
      z-index: 1;
      position:relative;
      margin: 0px;
      border: 2px solid #eaebed;
      padding: 2%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .col1-g {
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
      background-color: #a9a9a9;
      z-index: 1;
      position:relative;
      margin: 0px;
      border: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
      padding: 2%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .custreview {
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
      background-color: #eaebed;
      z-index: 1;
      position:relative;
      margin: 0px;
      border: 2px solid #eaebed;
      padding: 3%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .button {
        background-color: #F15A24;
        border-color: #F15A24;
        border-radius:5px;
        padding: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin: 8px;
        cursor: pointer;
        width:25%;
    
    
    }
    
    .button {
        background-color: #F15A24;
        border-color: #F15A24;
        border-radius:5px;
        padding: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin: 8px;
        cursor: pointer;
        width:25%;
    }
    
    .buttonport {
        background-color: #F15A24;
        border-color: #F15A24;
        border-radius:5px;
        padding: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin: 8px;
        cursor: pointer;
        width:25%;
    }
    
    .contactbar {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 45px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin:0px;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .spacer {
      width:100%;
      height:300px;
      opacity: 0.2;
      background-color: grey;
    }
    
    
    .spacersm {
      width:100%;
      height:100px;
      opacity: 0.6;
      background-color: grey;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
    
    }
    
    header {
      z-index: 1;
      margin: 0px;
      position: relative;
      display: inline;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
    }
    p {
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    ul {
      margin:0px;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0px;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      position: relative;
      top: 35px;
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    li {
      display: inline;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    a {
        text-decoration-line:none;
        color: inherit;
    }
    
    .footer {
      position:relative;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height:100px;
      background: linear-gradient(#a9a9a9,white);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    li a:hover {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: overline;
    }
    
    a:link, a:visited {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    p {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 490px) {
    
    .topbar {
      height: 50px;
    }
    .contactbar {
      font-size: 22px;
    }
    #headerlogo {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    ul {
      font-size: 22px;
    }
    h3 {
      font-size: 35px;
    }
    .spacer {
      height:550px;
    }
    
    .buttonport {
      font-size: 22px;
      width: 35%;
    }
    .content {
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: inherit;
    }
    .col1-1 {
      width: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      height:850px;
    }
    .col1-g {
      width: 50%;
      display:inline-block;
      right: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      height:850px;
    }
     .button {
       font-size: 22px;
       width: 35%;
     }
    .footer {
      height: 135px;
    }
    .smicon {
      height: 60px;
      width: 60px;
    }
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    
      #iPhone {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 175px;
      }
    
      .parallax {
        width: 80%;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
      }
    
      ul {
        font-size: 25px;
      }
    
      .content {
        font-size: 22px;
      }
    
      .buttonport {
          border-radius:5px;
          font-size: 22px;
          display: inline-block;
          margin-top: 13%;
          cursor: pointer;
      }
    
    }
```

```html
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name = "viewport" content= "width=device-width">
        <meta name = "keywords" content = "web design, mobile website, affordable design, professional website">
        <meta name = "autor" content = "Simon Dean">
        <title> Spartan | Designs </title>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="./css/mobile.css">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.slider').bxSlider();
        });
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
    
    <div class="parallax"></div>
    
        <header>
    <div class = "topbar">
      <p class = "contactbar"> 01642 747420  </p>
      <p class="contactbar"> contact@spartan.co.uk </p>
    </div>
    
    <div id = "logobar">
    
      <img id = "headerlogo" src = "img/Logo1.png" >
    
    </div>
    
      <nav id = "navmenu">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
        </header>
    
         <div class = "spacer"></div>
    
          <div class = "col1-1"> <h3> Bring your ideas to life </h3>
            <p class = "content"> Spartan|Design can help you realise the perfect web site whatever
              your requirements, would you like to know more? </p>
              <br>
              <div class="slider">
                <div><img class = "jQuery" src = "./img/web.jpeg"></div>
                <div><img class = "jQuery" src = "./img/web.jpeg"></div>
                <div><img class = "jQuery" src = "./img/web.jpeg"></div>
                <div><img class = "jQuery" src = "./img/web.jpeg"></div>
              </div>
            <a href="#" class="button">Contact us</a>
          </div>
    
          <div class = "col1-g">
            <h3>We have been busy!</h3>
            <p class = "content">Would you like to get a better idea of what Spartan|Design can offer you?
            Check in with some of our previous clients</p>
    
            <div><img id = "iPhone" src = "./img/iphone.png"></div>
    
            <a href="#" class="buttonport">Portfolio</a>
          </div>
    
      <div class="spacersm"> </div>
    
      <div class = "custreview"> <h2> Drawing from experience </h2>
        <p class="content"> We know it can be stressful when trying to choose the right development
          company for your website. As a result we allow our clients to be as hands
          on as they need to be during the development process, you will inform us of your design
        ideas or requirements and we will bring them to life. </p>
    <br>
          </div>
    
      <div class = "spacersm"></div>
    
        <div class = "footer">
          <ul>
            <li> <img class = "smicon" src="img/facebook.png"  alt="Facebook" longdesc="http://www.facebook.com"></li>
            <li> <img class = "smicon" src="img/instagram.png"  alt="Instagram" longdesc="http://www.instagram.com"></li>
            <li> <img class = "smicon" src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" longdesc="http://www.twitter.com"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </body>
```

If anyone can shed any light on this for me I would be very grateful, apoligies if the question seems too simple.

Comment: inspect your logo DOM and try to change css from there (developer console) and observe the  behaviour of DOM at different resolution.

Comment: I have done this and I am yet to find a solution, do you by any chance know why it would appear fine when condensed in the browser itself but appears with lines in responsive view.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "viewed in responsive mode" and "..outside of responsive mode"? Do you different HTML pages - with and without meta viewport commands - or something else? Maybe screenshots would clarify things.

Comment: If I view the page with chrome dev tools and set the device view to responsive, the second container shows two small gaps through which I can see my background image.

If I view the site in the chrome browser as you normally would, I do not see this small gap.